# Expected values of a quotient random variable/deterministic variable

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a random variable and $t$ is a strictly positive determininstic variable. What are the expected value and variance of the quotient $\frac{X}{t}$ and how to calculate them from basic properties?

Comment: The expected value is $\frac{E(X)}{t}$.

Comment: And the variance is $\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{t^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $Y:=\frac{1}{t}$

The expected value of a product of random variables is the product of the expected values,
if the random variables are independent, which is the case for $X$ and $Y$ here. So,

$$E\left(\frac{X}{t}\right)=E(X)E(Y)=\frac{E(X)}{t}$$

$$E\left(\left(\frac{X}{t}\right)^2\right)=E(X^2)E(Y)^2=\frac{E(X^2)}{t^2}$$

$$Var\left(\frac{X}{t}\right)=\frac{E(X)^2-E(X^2)}{t^2}$$

Here, I used $Var(X) = E(X)^2-E(X^2)$

Comment: For completeness $Var\left(\dfrac{X}{t}\right)=\dfrac{E(X)^2-E(X^2)}{t^2} = \dfrac{Var(X)}{t^2}$